# How to create a chrome (extension) webRequest listener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a [chrome (extension) webRequest listener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). However, no matter what I try I cannot get access to the `chrome.webRequest` object - my program crashes with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCompleted' of undefined`. Also debugging on the command line shows that `chrome.webRequest` does not exist.

My suspicion is that I am doing something wrong in the permissions, as I did not see many other stackoverflow questions or chrome bug reports with the same issues.

This is my **manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "my extension",
    "description": "my extension description",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "https://<myextension>.com/*",
    ],

    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": {                    // optional
            "19": "myextension.png",           // optional
            "38": "myextension.png"            // optional
        }
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://<myextension>.com/*"],
            "css": ["myextension.css"],
            "js": ["jquery.js", "myextension.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my **myextension.js**

```
var myfilter = {
    urls: ['https://myextension.com/*']
}

function mycallback(){
    console.log('received request response');
}

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(mycallback, myfilter);
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
I am running `OSX 10.10.2` and `chrome 40.0.2214.94`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the Chrome API cannot be used in [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), including `webRequest`:

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> Use `chrome.*` APIs, with the exception of:
>
> - `extension` ( `getURL` , `inIncognitoContext` , `lastError` , `onRequest` , `sendRequest` )
> - `i18n`
> - `runtime` ( `connect` , `getManifest` , `getURL` , `id` , `onConnect` , `onMessage` , `sendMessage` )
> - `storage`

You need to process this event in a background page and communicate with the context script using [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).